# Como agrego estilos en en el hover de las opciones de un select

Tags: css, html-select, hover

Quiero que el color de "hover" ( por que no se si se le llama asi ) que tiene por defecto tenga otro color

(ese color azul que muestra la sig imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano mucahs gracias !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388011/how-to-change-colour-of-blue-highlight-on-select-box-dropdown/19388345

Comment: No se nada de css, pero espero que este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7647/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-cambiar-el-color-del-hover-sobre-un-link-dentro-de-una-lista-de-elem) te pueda ayudar